# Responsive CSS Grid

Tags: css, responsive-design

Can someone help me add responsive css to this grid? I want each grid item to stack on a mobile device.

https://codepen.io/benpjam/pen/ebMJRW

HTML

## Paid Media

Online paid media can be a powerful strategy for lead generation and sales. With data-drive optimizations and ongoing management, paid media can also be a very cost-effective option for advertisers.

## Paid Media

Online paid media can be a powerful strategy for lead generation and sales. With data-drive optimizations and ongoing management, paid media can also be a very cost-effective option for advertisers.

## SEO

Search engine optimization is more than the keywords on you website. From local citations to meta data to schema markup, you SEO strategy must be technical and thoughtful in its approach.

## Web Development

We create eye-catching, high performance websites that are built from scratch. No templates or cookie cutter designs- just stunning, responsive, conversion-optimized websites and landing pages.

## Data & Analytics

Data should influence each decision that is made in your marketing strategy. With the right KPIs at-hand, we will slice each data point to understand how to make the most impactful optimizations.

CSS

```
    .container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  justify-content:center;
}

.lawyer-form {
  background-color:blue;
  min-height: 500px;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row:1/5;
}

.paid-media {
  background-color:red;
  min-height:100px;
  grid-column:3/5;
    grid-row:1/3;
  padding:20px;
}

.seo {
  background-color:green;
  min-height:100px;
  grid-column:3/5;
    grid-row:3/5;
  padding:20px;
}

.web-dev {
  background-color:yellow;
  min-height:100px;
  grid-column:5/7;
    grid-row:1/3;
  padding:20px;
}

.analytics {
  background-color:orange;
  min-height:100px;
  grid-column:5/7;
    grid-row:3/5;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi and weclome to SOF ! You need to use media queries here ! The idea will be to have the `grid-row` showing 1 instead of 4 on mobile

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

Ben,

The way I would do this is first write your CSS to display correctly on mobile. For displaying on mobile, you do not want grid applied. After you get the mobile to look how you want, you use the media query to apply the grid when over a specific px size.

Hope this helps.

you can find my markups css here:

```
.lawyer-form {
 background-color:blue;
 min-height: 500px;
 grid-column: 1/3;
 grid-row:1/5;
}
.paid-media {
 background-color:red;
 min-height:100px;
 grid-column:3/5;
 grid-row:1/3;
 padding:20px;
}

.seo {
 background-color:green;
 min-height:100px;
 grid-column:3/5;
 grid-row:3/5;
 padding:20px;
}

.web-dev {
 background-color:yellow;
 min-height:100px;
 grid-column:5/7;
 grid-row:1/3;
 padding:20px;
}

.analytics {
 background-color:orange;
 min-height:100px;
 grid-column:5/7;
 grid-row:3/5;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
 .container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
  justify-content:center;
}}
```

https://codepen.io/parisotdev/pen/oJqxdg